# SUM() of rows in Trigger(PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This is the table "Cars":
Cars(carId,color,price);

```
carId------color-------price
125         red        20000
101         blue       10000
104         black      30000
125         orange     15000
-and so on
```

I want to create a trigger, which will verify before insertion, if the sum of price is greater than
30000. And here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CarSum
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Cars FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
     v_sum Cars.price%TYPE; 
BEGIN
     SELECT SUM(price)
     INTO v_sum 
     FROM Cars
     WHERE :NEW.carId=Cars.carId;
    if v_sum >30000 then
        raise_application_error(-20000,'Very expensive');
    end if;
    
END;
```

/

```
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(125,"red",10000);
```

And I get this error: ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

I tried to do it with views(create a virtual table of Cars,and use it in trigger instead of Cars), but it isn't working.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where a trigger is required?  This is not the sort of thing that you'd really want a trigger to enforce in real life.

Comment: yes, the trigger is required. I just want to know how it works on this example

Comment: OK.  Has your class covered compound triggers and collections?

Comment: You can't select from the same table which is being updated. Once you fix your other issues, you will likely get a Mutating table exception.  Look at a COMPOUND trigger to figure out how to get around that.

Comment: So it's impossible to do that without Compount triggers?

Comment: If you want something that is quite inefficient, you could use a statement level trigger.  But that would require that you do the calculation for every `carID` every time any row changes rather than doing it just for the particular `carID` that changed.

Comment: Is carID a unique key (looks like it probably is).  If so, then there is nothing to sum() because you only have one of them.    And I am sick to death of instructors giving assignments that "require" the improper use of various features.  It really makes me question the validity of the course, but I see a lot of it on the various Oracle forums.

Comment: As an aside, MixedCaseNames are not a good idea in Oracle.  If you create them _without_ enclosing them in double-quotes, they will be case-INsensitive, which is what you want.  But they will actually be named as all caps.  So 'create table MyTable' actually creates MYTABLE.  And if you _do_ enclose in double-quotes, the will be created in exactly the case you specify, so you will _always_ have to enclose them and specify the correct case.  Better to _not_ use double-quotes, and create names with underscores for visual separation:  create table my_table.

Comment: and replace the double quotes with single one wrapping up the color value. e.g. `red`.